# Strange Local DNS issue involving Comcast, not a Comcast User

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, hostname

I have a network with 3 desktops (2 x Win7 x64, 1 x Win7 x32) connected via ethernet and 1 laptop (Win7 x64) connected via wireless most of the time using a Linksys WRT54GS.

I have a desktop statistics program running and noticed very high volume download traffic on one PC (Over .5GB before the computer finished booting, and it's not that slow! and it just continues).

I opened the resource meter to see who was hogging the bandwidth and saw it was the "System" process, not too helpful.

But in the connections field I noticed;

c-XX-XX-XX-XX.in.comcast.net - Where XX's are Octets of the IP addresses of my locally connected PC's.

(I am not a Comcast customer. I am in Europe, Ireland specifically, we don't even have Comcast here...)

I found;

tvnserver - TightVNC's Server application.
Acronis Sync Manager - I disabled this service.
And the System Process.
And a few others...

All referring to other systems on the network in this manner.

The IP addresses and Hostnames work as they should, but I can also pull up my webserver locally via this alter-ego.

I can ping them and it resolves with the actual IP.

Any idea why my computers are referring to themselves in this manner??

Comment: Have you checked for malware?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yep checked and double checked, and I can see IP cameras etc and reach them this way. It's something in the DNS settings, most likely in the router because all of the systems are referring to one another like this. I just don't know what to call it, they have hostnames, they work. They have IP Addresses, they work. And now I have this? Someone will come along and call it a 'feature' soon...

Comment: Is the WRT64GS configured to use something other than one of the blackhole set aside for local networks such as 192.168.1.x (the linksys default) or 10.10.10.x  It sounds like your local network is configured with real internet IP addresses instead of ranges set aside for local addresses.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Perhaps, I use 24.12.46.XX, someone told me not to use 192.168.1.X etc because if I am connecting to the router via VPN it could cause issues, systems on my network could conflict with the local network etc. Any idea how the router would place the Comcast hostname after my local IP's, and with the dashes if I conflicted with one of their subnets? I thought local and remote, LAN & WAN, were kept seperate... Also what would it be, ie. the systems respond to hostname, IP Address, and /this/ whatever you would call it??